# Facebook Search Api without access token

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

In many posts I have seen that the access_token is required in order to search specific keywords. Is not it possible without it. When I request it through web browser I receive the results. Then why I receive them via the browser?

Comment: Because you need to be logged in to search; in the API this is done via the access token, in the frontend it's done via your account being logged in

Answer (score 0):

Igy explained it perfectly. You are logged into Facebook while using your account, so you have access based on your user perspective. These searches are tailored to your account

An application does not represent you unless you grant it access to see searched.